# Using cloud storage service as online hosting for android app's media resources

Tags: android, cloud, hosting

Is it possible to use cloud storage services such as google drive or dropbox to be used as an online hosting for my app's media resources?

I am developing an app which will be using an online server or storage to retrieve media files like videos and pictures.

I dont want to buy a server so would it be possible for the users to save and retrieve files through cloud services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most of the main cloud storage providers support this.

Some examples:

Dropbox has an Android SDK and includes an example app that shares photos between and Android device and their cloud storage.

Parse.com has an Android SDK and provides tutorials, one of which is a photo sharing app which would probably be worth you looking at in particular (https://www.parse.com/tutorials).